# Account email validation important or not?

Tags: captcha

On a social/user based websites, where user registration is required, why it is important(or general trend) to validate the account (by sending confirmation link to the email). If during the registration process, a good captcha system (for example recaptcha) is used, Is there still need to use email validation? 
What advantage it gives?

Answer (score 2):

Email confirmation prevents miscreants from maliciously subscribing other people to sites with content they're not interested in.

Any reputable site that requires registration will ensure that the owner of the email address actually does want to subscribe/register for their services and content.

This is done by verifying that the supplied email address is being used legitimately by way of an email containing a confirmation/verification link that must be clicked to complete the registration.

Such a registration system would typically allow up to 24 hours for the verification to be completed, otherwise the pending registration will be deleted.

This permits recipients who accidentally or otherwise receive one of these emails ignore the fake/unintended/mistaken registration and if necessary contact the site owners if there is evidence of malicious intent.

Answer (score 0):

It validates the email account for one: checking if the email supplied is actually a real email, and the user who made the account (and knows the password) can actually use that email  address.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from what Kev already stated, the e-mail verification can prove useful for two additional reasons:

1. It gives a reliable method for password resetting in case the user forgot the password for his/her account.
2. It provides the "*social/user based website with*" a reliable channel of communication with the user to inform of important updates on Terms of Service, account termination notice, etc.